# How to get hiddenfield in itemtemplate of gridview in button click

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which itemtemplate contains hiddenfield.I have a button outside gridview.In the click event of button ,i want to get the value of hiddenfield of `Rows(0)`,means first row.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
string hiddenFieldValue = ((HiddenField) yourGridView.Rows[0].FindControl("yourHiddentFieldName")).Value;
```

(sorry it's not in VB.Net but I can't write in that language).

Answer (score 2):

In simple way

```
HiddenField hdf = (HiddenField)grd.Rows[0].FindControl("hidden1");
    String value = hdf.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

`DirectCast(GridView.Rows(0).FindControl("MyHiddenField"),HiddenField).Value` is the VB version.